# Как получить все четные суммы делителей в промежутке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = int (input())
b = int (input())

def sumchis(i):
    sum = 0
    d = [x for x in range(1, i // 2 + 1) if i % x == 0 ]
    d.append(i)
    for j in d:
        sum += j
    return(sum)
def sop(a, b, sumchis):
    chet = []
    vsedel = []
    alch3 = []
    for i in range(a, b + 1):
        alch3.append(i)
        ch = sumchis(i)
        vsedel.append(str(ch))
        if ch % 2 == 0:
            chet.append(str(ch))

    return (chet, vsedel, alch3)


print(sop(a, b, sumchis))
```

Cейчас код выводит 3 списка `chet` - только четные суммы всех делителей (т.е. 3 = 1+3, выведет 4, а 4 = 1+2+4 = 7, выводить не станет
`vsedel` - сумму всех делителей, каждого числа
`alch3` - все числа
Не понимаю как сделать это:
Надо вывести все числа (в промежутке) , сумма делителей которых четные.
Я думаю надо получить индексы в списке `vsedel` всех элементов, которые совпадают со списком `chet`, а затем по этим индексам надо получить элементы списка `alch3` и уже их вывести.
Сформулировать получается, а вот в коде уже путаюсь

Comment: Сами делители не обязаны быть чётными? Тогда исправьте заголовок. А то в заголовке одно, а в теле вопроса другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чем проблема то?

1. найти все чётные делители числа в промежутке между a и b
2. пройти рекурсивно по списку делителей
3. в качестве оптимизации найденные суммы можно добавлять в множество, чтобы не дублировать выводы

получается такой код:

```
def sums(dividers, pos = 0, res = 0, total = set()):
 
    # перебираем все делители из оставшихся
    for index in range(pos, len(dividers)):
        
        # вычисляем новую сумму
        new_sum = res + dividers[index]

        # если новой суммы еще не было получено ранее - 
        #   выводим результат и добавляем сумму в множество найденных ранее сумм
        if new_sum not in total:
            print(new_sum )
            total.add(new_sum )

        # рекурсивно вычисляем сумму делителей
        sums(dividers, pos + 1, new_sum , total)


n = 12
a = 2
b = 5

# определяем необходимые делители (в диапазоне [a, b] и четные)
dividers = [x for x in range(a, b + 1) if n % x == 0 and x % 2 == 0]

# ищем все суммы выбранных делителей
sums(dividers)
```

Comment: Судя по коду и самому вопросу нужны не "чётные делители", а "делители, сумма которых чётная". И нужно вывести список чисел, у которых такие делители.

Comment: @CrazyElf, но в заголовку уже другое :) в любом случае код изменяется исключительно местом где будет стоять проверка на чётность :)

Comment: Как изменить заголовок? Первый раз на сайте

Comment: @КириллИльиных Кнопкой "править" под вопросом, наверное. Там и тело вопроса и заголовок можно править, если ничего не путаю.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо